# Is Lambert W-function possible for this type of equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, lambert-w

I am trying to find the Lambert W solution of the following equation, but I am not able to proceed further because I am not able to put the equation in the form of $x=W(x)\exp(W(x))$.

The equation is:
$$d = x(1+x) + \ln(1+x)$$
where $d$ is constant.

I am looking for real solutions.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I tried it with Wolfram Alpha for d=$50$ and it returned only a numerical solution , hence I guess Lambert-W does not help here.

Comment: @Sudesh To prevent closing by others, you should write in your question where your equation or interest in this equation comes from and whether the constants and solutions should be complex numbers or perhaps just real numbers.

Comment: Are you looking for real or complex solutions?

Comment: I am looking for real solutions.

Comment: @TymaGaidash Actually here my goal is to invert the trajectory of the function and write in terms of the Lambert W function.

Comment: Can you give some directions regarding the integral or sum representation of the inverse?

Comment: @Sudesh Please see the new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$d=x(1+x)+\ln(1+x)$$
$$\ln(1+x)+x^2+x-d=0$$

We see, the equation is a polynomial equation of more than one algebraically independent monomials ($x,\ln(1+x)$) and with no univariate factor. We therefore don't know how to rearrange the equation for $x$ by applying only finite numbers of [elementary functions (operations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function) we can read from the equation.

**a)**

$$d=x(1+x)+\ln(1+x)$$

Let's exponentiate both sides of the equation, as proposed by one of the comments.

$$e^d=(1+x)e^{x(1+x)}$$

We see, this equation is not in a form for applying Lambert W or Generalized Lambert W.

**b)**

$$d=x(1+x)+\ln(1+x)$$
$x\to e^t-1$:
$$d=(e^t-1)e^t+\ln(e^t)$$
i.a. for $t\in\mathbb{R}$:
$$d=\left(e^t\right)^2-e^t+t\tag{1}$$

We see, this equation is not in a form for applying Lambert W or Generalized Lambert W.

We see, equation (1) is an irreducible algebraic equation of $t$ and $e^t$ simultaneously if $d$ is an algebraic number.
According to the theorems in [Lin 1983] and [Chow 1999], such kind of equations cannot have solutions except $0$ that are [elementary numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_number) or explicit elementary numbers respectively. And $x$ can therefore also not be an elementary number except $0$.
$\ $

[[Lin 1983] Ferng-Ching Lin: Schanuel's Conjecture Implies Ritt's Conjectures. Chin. J. Math. 11 (1983) (1) 41-50](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43836165)

[[Chow 1999] Chow, T.: What is a closed-form number. Am. Math. Monthly 106 (1999) (5) 440-448](http://timothychow.net/closedform.pdf)

[Mező 2017] Mező, I.: On the structure of the solution set of a generalized Euler-Lambert equation. J. Math. Anal. Appl. 455 (2017) (1) 538-553

[Mező/Baricz 2017] Mező, I.; Baricz, Á.: On the generalization of the Lambert W function. Transact. Amer. Math. Soc. 369 (2017) (11) 7917–7934 [(On the generalization of the Lambert W function with applications in theoretical physics. 2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1408.3999)

[[Castle 2018] Castle, P.: Taylor series for generalized Lambert W functions. 2018](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09904)

Comment: So according to your answer, I cannot invert the trajectory of this function by using the Lambert W function.

Comment: Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

[Lagrange reversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_reversion_theorem) gives:

$$f(x)=x(x+1)+\ln(x+1)\implies f^{-1}(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{n!}\frac{d^{n-1} e^x(e^{2x}-e^x)^n}{dx^{n-1}}$$

Expand with the derivative’s argument with the binomial theorem and get:

$$\boxed{f^{-1}(x)=e^x-1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^n\frac{(-1)^m(m+n+1)^{n-1}e^{(m+n+1)x}}{(n-m)!m!}}$$

[shown](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5E%28-3%29-1.0%2Bsum%5Bsum%5B%28-1%29%5En%2Fn%21+binom%28n%2Cm%29+%28-1%29%5E%28n-m%29+e%5E+%28%281+%2B+m+%2B+n%29+%28-3%29%29+%281+%2B+m+%2B+n%29%5E%28n-1%29%2C%7Bm%2C0%2C6%7D%5D%2C%7Bn%2C1%2C6%7D%5D) [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x+%28x%2B1%29%2Bln%28x%2B1%29%3D-3)
when comparing links. It works for $x\le 0$:

[image]

Comment: thank you for your response